# How to perform an inverse selection of reads in a fastq file that do not contain a specific sequence

Tags: awk, grep, fastq

I have a fastq file from Illumina sequencing that consists of blocks of four lines like this

```
Line1=Header
Line2=DNAsequence
Line3=qheader
Line4=qseq
```

and would like to discard entire blocks where the DNAsequence contains a certain target sequence (which is a string of ACGT within a much longer string of the same letters).

I have used

```
grep -A 1 -B 2 "target-sequence" input.fastq > unwanted.fastq
```

which successfully selected the unwanted reads, e.g. blocks of four lines.

Now I can't work out how to write non-selected reads that do not contain the sequence.

I tried

```
grep -v -A 1 -B 2 "target-sequence" input.fastq > wanted.fastq
```

but that returns the original file.

I have tried using

```
grep -f unwanted.fastq input.fastq > wanted.fastq
```

or

```
diff unwanted.fastq input.fastq > wanted.fastq
```

to extract the selected reads from the original file, but that is using up too much memory on my machine.

I am aware that awk is good at manipulating fastq files, but I am not familiar with it.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear and also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your code and example.

Comment: It's good that you added sample input and formatted your question but you forgot to add the expected output given that input. From reading the text, it doesn't sound like the sample input you provided is adequate for us to test with, though, as it's just 1 block and you say your input contains multiple blocks from which you want to print or delete some subset of them. Actually it seems to describe your input rather then be sample input. f that's true then please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input/output that we can copy/paste to test a solution against.